# How to highlight a selected link in a page by an arrow mark under that active link?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

My html code is:

```
 <div id="arrow">
     <b>Filter By: </b>

    <a href="__#" onclick="GetAllTasks();" id="id_all" style="color: #88b807;">All</a> 

    <input type="text" size="3" style="display: none;" id="DateFilter" />

    <a href="__#" onclick="GetByDate(this);" style="vertical-align: middle;"   id="cal_icon">EndDate</a>

    <a href="#"__0  onclick="GetMyTasks();" id="id_myposts">My Requests</a>
    </div>
```

My css code is:

```
a:active  {font-family: Verdana, Sans-serif;
            color:#FF0000;
            text-decoration:none;

            background: url("Images/arrow_down.png") no-repeat;
            background-position:center;
            }
```

Here i want the arrow image to come under the active link so that it indicates that it is active.. 
I have tried the above code but i m not getting the desired output..

Comment: I have accepted the answers which gives me what i want.. But few are not what i expected.. So dats the reason oly 40%..

Apart from that can u tel me how to do that using jquery or any sample code regarding the same..

Comment: @deifwud
That Arrow image is not coming below the active link

Comment: Are you certain it's `active` that you want to apply the style to and not `hover` or `focus`?

Comment: Ya i have three links as specified above.. If i click a link it displays some info.. What i need is the arrow image should be displayed below the clicked link to intimate the user that it is the active link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display the arrow with pure CSS (see below), but you'll need javascript to keep the class "alive".

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/EBhVu/)** (click on a link)

HTML:

```
<b>Filter By: </b>
<a href="#">All</a> 
<a href="#">EndDate</a>
<a href="#">My Requests</a>
```

CSS:

```
a  {
    position:relative;
}
a:active:after, a.active:after  {
    background: url("Images/arrow_down.png");
    width:10px; /* arrow's width */
    height:10px; /* arrow's height */
    margin-left:-5px; /* half of arrow's width */
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    right:50%;
    content:" ";
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});​
```

Comment: I have tried as u specified.. But it says that content is not a valid property of css..

Comment: @Xavier you're using XHTML, aren't you? Well, check my edit, it should be valid now.

Comment: Ya that is working fine in chrome but not working in IE 8.. Is there any way to achive this in IE also

Comment: Yes, you've to include this javascript library: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ it's very useful for all "new" css selectors and pseudo-elements.

Comment: Kindly help me in another thing.. I need the "All" link to be selected by default.. So once the page is loaded it must be selected in default and the arrow image should be displayed below it to indicate that it is active..

Comment: @Xavier just change `<a href="#">All</a>` to `<a href="#" class="active">All</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use some script to do that. Create a separate class for active state and add that class on click.

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
});​
```

Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/qvQxp/1/

Answer (score 0):

I tried Giona's answer and found that the negative magin for margin-left was being ignored by the browser and the arrow was still off center by half the width of the arrow image. To fix this, apply the negative margin to margin-right instead.